# Would zero "t-ANOVA" scores imply zero mean differences?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I apologize for the noticeably contrived term "t-ANOVA". It is not really a [Student's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) at least because I am not necessarily assuming a t distribution, but it was a source of motivation. Nor is it an ANOVA test, although that was a source of motivation as well. I am open to suggestions for name revision in the comments.

---

The motivation of this statistic came about when I realized it would be easy to occupy a matrix with t-scores, and that the determinant might be a suitable aggregate function for testing differences about groups. I ended up squaring the t-scores below to avoid the uninteresting result that the determinant of an odd-dimension and antisymmetric matrix is always zero.

---

Let us assume we have a collection of random variables $A =\{ X_j \}_{j=1}^n$, each with suitable moments. Let's denote the sample mean of the $j$ variable to be $\bar{X}_j$. And let's also denote

$$T_{i,j}^2 = \left( \frac{\bar{X}_i - \bar{X}_j}{S_{\Delta}(i,j)} \right)^2$$

where $S_{\Delta}(i,j)$ is the pooled sample standard deviation of the variables $X_i, X_j \in A$.

Now let's turn to considering $\det \mathbf{T}$, the determinant of the non-negatively-valued symmetric matrix whose entries are $T_{i,j}^2$. It is clear for the series of multilinear terms in the determinant that if $T_{i,j}^2 = 0$ for all $i,j \in \{1, \cdots, n \}$, then $\det \mathbf{T}=0$.

But I am imagining that the converse is not true because non-zero terms could cancel out. But then again I may not be properly accounting for the symmetry of the matrix or signum of the permutations considered in computing the determinant. Perhaps a zero score would mean little more than linear dependence of either the rows or columns. **Can someone check me on that?**

---

For this question I have ignored whether to hypothesis test using an analytically-derived test score from an explicit probability model or by resampling methods.

Comment: You might want to look at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55236/28500) on the interpretation of a squared t-variate.

Comment: @EdM Yes, interesting. So under certain assumptions a product of $T^2$ scores as found in the determinant above will be a product of $F$-distributed random variables.